# How to manage the environment PATH used by the Android NDK build?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, system-paths

I use [swig](http://www.swig.org/) from my within Android.mk. I reference it directly relying on the $PATH variable to contain the path to it's executable.

The issue is that the $PATH variable is different depending on where the android-ndk tool is run from.

**Background**

In my Android.mk file:

```
# some stuff ...
@echo "$(PATH)"
swig # swig parameters here...
# more stuff ...
```

From the terminal, we see the system path includes the path to swig:

```
which swig
/usr/local/bin/swig
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
```

**Issue**

When the android-ndk is run from within Android Studio I get the following for PATH (note: it's missing the swig path):

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

This causes my build to fail because "swig" isn't recognised:

```
make: swig: Command not found
```

However, if I run the android-ndk directly from the terminal, then the PATH used is the same as my system path and the build works fine:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
```

**Bad solution**

Yes, I could add the path manually to my Android.mk file:

```
export PATH:=/usr/local/bin/:$(PATH)
```

However, I'd prefer not to define specific paths for my machine knowing that the whole team uses this file.

**Question**

I'd prefer the Android.mk file to use my systems PATH instead.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The thing in my opinion is that environment variables may be different whether the process is launched from terminal or from the GUI (launchpad, spotlight, ...).

The former would use `PATH` as set in `bashrc` (or other shell related startup files) while the other will not.

I think you might find interesting information on how to change the environment variables for the launch deamon in the following question:

[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)